# 'Like' button on Intranet Blog - SP2007

Tags: web-part, blog

does anyone know if a webpart exists for adding a 'like' button on a Sharepoint Blog post?

the button will not link to facebook (applet) it is solely for an Intranet site.

the counter for the 'likes' will appear next to Blog topic or inside the blog post. Either way is cool.

For Sharepoint 2007.

Cheers

Comment: did you get any answer for above, if yes could you help me out this. I have same kind of requirement.